# Can not show map when use google map api v2?

Tags: android, google-maps

I follow this link: [Here](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/drawing-driving-route-directions-between-two-locations-using-google-directions-in-google-map-android-api-v2/)

But when i run in my device. Can not show map. It's just show white screen with logo google at left.

Some body can help me please? Sorry because my english.

Comment: check your api key and make sure your internet connection is on.

Comment: How you run the app through USB or Install apk file separately.

Comment: I send install api file to real device by bluetooth. @Yugesh

Comment: Check out : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Comment: @user3706741 USB debugging have separate API key and Release mode have separate API key.Refer Android Document.You get clear idea.

Comment: can you show me how to do it? @Yugesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create debugging API key and Release API key.

**Step 1:**

```
In Commend Prompt

Now locate to jdk in C drive(Considering for windows and assigning C drive)

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore E:\A.keystore -alias A

So it will create SHA-1 finger print.
```

A.keystore is an Keystore, for debugging this file found in `C:\Users\User\.android` file name is `debug.keystore`, for release you created the Keystore file.

**Step 2**

```
Go to google api console.
Generate new api key for android you have to used this SHA-1 and current playstore package name.
Put Api key into your map.
```

Comment: I did. But my app still not work. still white screen...@Yugesh

Comment: @user3706741 Which API key you used in your application release or debug.

Comment: i used release. @Yugesh

Comment: Okay.How you create the APK.

Comment: I run my app with ADT and copy apk from bin folder.

Comment: That is debug apk not an release apk @user3706741

Comment: So, How to get release apk? Can you show me? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Hades10 Did you use Android studio or Eclipse

Comment: I use Eclipse. @Yugesh

Comment: @Hades10 Check this [Link](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Signing_and_Preparing_an_Android_Application_for_Release)

Comment: When I create API key. need I create a new project or can I use API project? @Yugesh

Comment: Create API key only no need to create new API project @Hades10

Comment: @Hades10 you are welcome.And small suggestion when you post the question in this site,explain it clearly.Otherwise your question getting down voted.